# How do you align \@hangfrom paragraphs?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, numbering, lists

I'm trying to write up an interview with numbered questions to look something like this:

```
Q1.    What is your name?
A.     My name is Sir Lancelot of Camelot.
Q2.    What is your quest?
A.     To seek the Holy Grail.
Q3.    What is your favourite colour?
A.     Blue.
```

So far I've been using a counter and the `\@hangfrom` macro:

```
\newcounter{qanda}
\setcounter{qanda}{1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\question[1]{%
  \@hangfrom{\bfseries Q\arabic{qanda}.\hspace{5mm}}{\bfseries #1\par}%
}
\newcommand*\answer[1]{%
  \@hangfrom{\bfseries A.\hspace{5mm}}{#1\par}%
  \addtocounter{qanda}{1}%
}
\makeatother

\question{What is your name?}
\answer{My name is Sir Lancelot of Camelot.}
```

The problem is that the text of the questions and answers doesn't end up being aligned, since the Qs are followed by numbers. Is there a way to align the paragraphs? Is `\@hangfrom` the wrong tool to use here?

Comment: I would think that using a list (`enumerate`/`itemize`) would be a better option here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alignment of items does look better when moulding it into an `enumerate`/`itemize` environment. With the use of the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) you can manipulate the way the labels are formatted and aligned. Consider, for example, the following alternative to your question/answer setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem

\newcounter{question}
\newcommand*{\question}{\stepcounter{question}\item[Q\thequestion.]}%
\newcommand*{\answer}{\item[A.]}%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[align=left]
  \question What is your name?
  \answer My name is Sir Lancelot of Camelot.
  \question What is your quest?
  \answer To seek the Holy Grail.
  \question What is your favourite colour?
  \answer Blue.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Questions & answers]

Two macros allow for questions `\question` and answers `\answer`. The question has an associated counter with a representation that is `Q{#}.` and answer is just typeset as `A.`. Both the labels will be left-aligned using the latest version `v3.0` of `enumitem`s `align=left` option. These can be modified as needed.

---

**Addendum:** Since you may have a large number of question and could potentially refer to some of them, you could use labels. This requires a slight modification to the existing code: `\stepcounter` -> `\refstepcounter`. Now you can use:

```
...\refstepcounter{question}...
...
\begin{enumerate}[align=left]
  \question What is your name?
  \answer My name is Sir Lancelot of Camelot.
  \question What is your quest? \label{quest}
  \answer To seek the Holy Grail.
  \question What is your favourite colour?
  \answer Blue.
  \question Please elaborate on Q\ref{quest}.
  \answer I'm a Monty Python enthusiast.
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I suspected I should have been using enumerate. Is there a way to have the questions and answers be left-justified?

Comment: @Raghav: Yes. I've updated my answer to reflect this. You'll need the latest version of `enumitem`, since the option `align=<alignment>` was introduced in `v3.0`. See the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for more on this.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcounter{qanda}

\newenvironment{QandA}
  {\par\noindent\tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}p{6mm}>{\bfseries}X}}
  {\endtabularx}

\newcommand\question[1]{\global\refstepcounter{qanda}%
  Q\arabic{qanda} & #1\tabularnewline}
\newcommand\answer[1]{A & #1\tabularnewline}
\begin{document}

\begin{QandA}
\question{What is your name?}
\answer{My name is Sir Lancelot of Camelot.}
\question{What is your quest?}
\answer{To seek the Holy Grail.}
\question{What is your favourite colour?}
\answer{Blue.}
\end{QandA}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will not allow your `QandA` to span more than one page, due to the limitation of using `tabularx`.

Comment: sure, it will with  `\usepackage{ltablex}`